# perl (5.30.0) install failure on MacOS 10.14.6

Tags: perl, installation, perlbrew

I have an up to date copy of XCode: Version 11.0 (11A420a)
I use perlbrew to do installs, and the last successful one was 5-28.0 Jul 26 2018

Here is that tail of the log:

```
    Finishing processing Unicode properties
    Compiling Perl properties
    Creating Perl synonyms
    Writing tables
    Making pod file
    Making test script
    Updating 'mktables.lst'
    ./miniperl -Ilib -MExtUtils::Miniperl -e 'writemain(\"perlmain.c", @ARGV)' DynaLoader 
    cc -c -DPERL_CORE -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -std=c89 -O3 -Wall -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=pointer-arith -Wextra -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings perlmain.c
    cc -c -DPERL_CORE -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -std=c89 -O3 -Wall -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=pointer-arith -Wextra -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings op.c
    cc -c -DPERL_CORE -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -std=c89 -O3 -Wall -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=pointer-arith -Wextra -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings perl.c
    ./miniperl -Ilib make_ext.pl DynaLoader.o  MAKE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make" LIBPERL_A=libperl.a LINKTYPE=static CCCDLFLAGS=
    Generating a Unix-style Makefile
    Writing Makefile for DynaLoader
    "../../miniperl" "-I../../lib" DynaLoader_pm.PL DynaLoader.pm
    rm -f DynaLoader.xs
    cp dl_dlopen.xs DynaLoader.xs
    "../../miniperl" "-I../../lib" "../../lib/ExtUtils/xsubpp" -noprototypes -typemap '/Users/roger/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.30.0/perl-5.30.0/ext/DynaLoader/../../lib/ExtUtils/typemap'  DynaLoader.xs > DynaLoader.xsc
    mv DynaLoader.xsc DynaLoader.c
    cc -c   -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -Wall -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=pointer-arith -Wextra -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.45\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.45\"  "-I../.."  -DLIBC="" DynaLoader.c
    rm -rf ../../DynaLoader.o
    cp DynaLoader.o ../../DynaLoader.o
    rm -f libperl.a
    /opt/local/bin/ar rc libperl.a op.o     perl.o  gv.o toke.o perly.o pad.o regcomp.o dump.o util.o mg.o reentr.o mro_core.o keywords.o hv.o av.o run.o pp_hot.o sv.o pp.o scope.o pp_ctl.o pp_sys.o doop.o doio.o regexec.o utf8.o taint.o deb.o universal.o globals.o perlio.o perlapi.o numeric.o mathoms.o locale.o pp_pack.o pp_sort.o caretx.o dquote.o time64.o   DynaLoader.o
    /opt/local/bin/ranlib: object: libperl.a(op.o) malformed object (unknown load command 1)
    /opt/local/bin/ar: internal ranlib command failed
    make: *** [libperl.a] Error 1
    ##### Brew Failed #####
```

Comment: This looks like the same compilation issue as was reported with ruby, only this time with Perl. Possible duplicate of [Cannot install any version of ruby on Mojave - internal ranlib command failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54363030/cannot-install-any-version-of-ruby-on-mojave-internal-ranlib-command-failed)